# Matplotlib scatter plot of subset of uneven length arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I can create a lovely scatter plot of multiple arrays of varying lengths:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1+2j, 2+3j, 3+4j]
b = [1+3j, 2+4j, 3+5j]
c = [1+4j, 2+5j, 3+6j, 4+7j]

abc = [a, b, c]
colours = ['blue', 'orange', 'green']
for aa,c in zip(abc, colours):
    aaa = np.array(aa)
    scat = plt.scatter(aaa.real, aaa.imag, c=c)
```

[image: Scatter plot]

But if I want to do it dynamically with `set_offsets`, things go screwy as soon as the arrays are different length:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1+2j, 2+3j, 3+4j]
b = [1+3j, 2+4j, 3+5j]
c = [1+4j, 2+5j, 3+6j, 4+7j]

abc = [a, b, c]
colours = ['blue', 'orange', 'green']

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0.7, 4.3), ylim=(1.7, 7.3))
scat = ax.scatter([], [], c=colours)
paa = []
for aa in abc:
    paa.append(aa[0:SUBSET_IDX])
paaa = np.vstack([paa]).flatten('F')
scat.set_offsets(np.c_[paaa.real, paaa.imag])
```

If `SUBSET_IDX` is 2, happy days. But if it's 4, nothing gets plotted! Yet `paaa` is what you would expect:

```
array([[(1+2j), (2+3j), (3+4j)], [(1+3j), (2+4j), (3+5j)],
   [(1+4j), (2+5j), (3+6j), (4+7j)]], dtype=object)
```

How do I get set_offsets to accept arrays of different lengths?

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but I found I can workaround this issue by padding any short arrays with dummy data:

```
for aa in abc:
    paa.append(aa[0:SUBSET_IDX] + [0+0j] * (SUBSET_IDX-len(aa))))
```